# I'm trying to list down all access Shared access policies of Azure Service Bus and coudn't found a starting point

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I need to list down access policies of all service buses. Is there a possibilty to get this using KQL? Or Dotnet?

Comment: Please mention what you tried and the result you got in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with KQL, I guess?

But you could use ARM, Bicap, or Service Bus REST API to get Service Bus Shared Access Key.

**Option: 1**

[Documentation - ARM Templates - listkeys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#listkeys)

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules          listkeys 
Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules   listkeys 
Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/authorizationRules   listkeys
```

**Option: 2**

[Documentation - Bicep - listkeys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#list)

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules          listkeys 
Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules   listkeys 
Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/authorizationRules   listkeys
```

**Option: 3**

[REST Service Bus Namespaces - Authorization Rules API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/namespaces-authorization-rules/list-keys?tabs=HTTP)